What is the correct formula for the 3 dB frequency of an RC or LC Circuit?
Before we jump to another post where the formula is

I am reading through the text book Microelectronic Circuits 8th edition by SEDRA/SMITH. In the text, they show this table.

Here it shows the time constant as RC or L/R which is fine but it then shows Wo as 1/RC or 1/(L/R) which is is missing the 2pi from the first equation I have shown.
Which is the correct formula? is there a meaning that i do not understand for removing the 2pi? or are there specific circumstances where the 2pi is not applicable?
Note: The text book refers to this term with the following:
"3-dB frequency (Wo) is also known as the corner frequency, break frequency, or pole frequency"

Replying to my question since i realized that the first formula is for frequency and the second is for Wo which is just 2pif. So they are are same formula.

Yeah, the phrase angular frequency is sometimes used for $\omega$ and just frequency for $f$. However, it's usually expected that a reader will be able to work out which is which from the context and formula. If you see $\sin\left(r,t\right)$ you probably should not take it that $r$ is in Hertz. Rather, that $r$ is likely an angular frequency that is $2\pi$ times the frequency in Hertz. You just get used to it and try to avoid obvious mistakes when calculating values like those for a capacitor, etc., since being wrong by a factor of 6 does matter when ordering parts.

Angular frequency Omega is 2pi*f so the formulas are correct.

Facts:

There are \$2\pi\$ radians in one complete revolution of a circle.
It's the circumference of a circle with radius 1.

If that circle revolves at 1 turn per second (equivalent to a frequency of 1 Hz) it will be spinning at \$2\pi\$ radians per second.
